# How to identify secular terms in multiscale expansion?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

How can one identify secular terms while doing multiscale expansion?

For e.g. in an initial value problem, can any term where t appears can be counted as secular term?

What about; $t e^{-t}$, is it a secular term?

Regards,

Nitin

Comment: If you have term on the RHS that is an eigenfunction of the differential operator in the LHS then you will get secular growth in your solution. Such terms must be eliminated. Look up "Fredholm Alternative" which is a way to show this. If you just have a $te^{-t}$ term on the RHS of your ODE I don't think one would call that a secular term in general.

Answer (score 12):

Secular terms appear in the solution to a perturbation problem, and indicate that the scaling has broken down.

A perturbation expansion looks like
$$ x(t)=x_0+\epsilon x_1(t)+\epsilon^2x_2(t)+\ldots,$$
where each term (i.e. each $\epsilon^ix_i$) is asymptotically smaller than the term before it. So $\epsilon x_1\ll x_0$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$, and $\epsilon^2x_2\ll\epsilon x_1$.

It is this ordering that allows you to separate your original equation into a series of equations that give approximate solutions.

In some cases though, your assumption that each term is asymptotically smaller than the one before it can break down. If you find a function $x_1(t)$ that grows in time, then eventually it will become larger than the $x_0$ term.

A classic example is the weakly nonlinear oscillator. Consider the IVP 
$$\ddot x+2\epsilon\dot x+x=0,\quad x(0)=0,\quad\dot x(0)=1.$$
Doing the normal perturbation expansion you find that $x_0=\sin(t)$, and $x_1=-t\sin(t)$. So your two-term solution is $x=\sin(t)-\epsilon t\sin(t)$. But when $t\sim1/\epsilon$, the solution looks like $x=0$ because your first and second order terms have balanced, and $x_0\sim\epsilon x_1$! So your original assumption implicit in solving for $x_0$ first, then $x_1$ and so on is not satisfied for large times.

To resolve this problem, you need to use the method of multiple scales.